# Add authentication token to AJAX call for a Web API secured using Azure Active Directory authentication

Tags: javascript, active-directory, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I have  a vanilla JavaScript based web page. I need to call my web API at https://XYZ.azurewebsites.net which is secured using Azure Active Directory authentication.

For doing this, I have added ADAL.js to my website, registered my website/webapp as Native Client in AAD. I am not sure about minimal amount of code to silently acquire the authentication token.

**What are the minimum steps I need to do for getting an authentication token in vanilla JavaScript?**

Note: I have gone through numerous sample on Azure AD auth on GitHub. But they all suggest to clone the repo and replace values for Audience, Tenants, etc. What I need is just a simple vanilla JS function to do the same without all the bloat code in those samples.

Comment: What do you mean by "silently acquire the authentication token". Do you mean you're trying to acquire a token without prompting the user to sign in?

Comment: Can you also specify which samples you attempted to use?

Comment: Hi, is it not possible to acquire token without prompting the user to login?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One straight-forward approach to using ADAL.JS (and vanilla JavaScript):

1. Configure the instance of `AuthenticationContext`.
2. Use `AuthenticationContext.login()` to sign in.
3. Use `AuthenticationContext.handleWindowCallback()` to handle token request responses.
4. Use `AuthenticationContext.acquireToken()` to get an access token.
5. Use the received access token to make your API requests.

Here's a full minimal example that obtains an access token to the [Microsoft Graph API](https://graph.microsoft.io) (an example of an API protected by Azure AD) and uses it to make an AJAX call to retrieve the signed-in user's profile. The numbers in the comments correspond to the steps above.

(I've also posted [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/psignoret/50e88652ae5cb6cc157c09857e3ba87f) with a slightly more complete version which you can [try out live](http://bl.ocks.org/psignoret/raw/50e88652ae5cb6cc157c09857e3ba87f/).)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Minimal sample using ADAL.JS</title>
        <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.11/js/adal.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <!-- #2: Use ADAL's login() to sign in -->
            <a href="#" onclick="authContext.login(); return false;">Log in</a> |
            <a href="#" onclick="authContext.logOut(); return false;">Log out</a>
        </p>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            // #1: Set up ADAL
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext({
                clientId: 'c24f035c-1ff6-4dfa-b76d-c75a29ad2c3c',
                postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location
            });

            // #3: Handle redirect after token requests
            if (authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash)) {

                authContext.handleWindowCallback();
                var err = authContext.getLoginError();
                if (err) {
                    // TODO: Handle errors signing in and getting tokens
                }

            } else {

                // If logged in, get access token and make an API request
                var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
                if (user) {

                    console.log('Signed in as: ' + user.userName);

                    // #4: Get an access token to the Microsoft Graph API
                    authContext.acquireToken(
                        'https://graph.microsoft.com',
                        function (error, token) {

                            // TODO: Handle error obtaining access token
                            if (error || !token) { return; }

                            // #5: Use the access token to make an AJAX call
                            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xhr.open('GET', 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', true);
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
                            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                                    // TODO: Do something with the response
                                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                                } else {
                                    // TODO: Do something with the error 
                                    // (or other non-200 responses)
                                }
                            };
                            xhr.send();
                        }
                    );
                } else {

                    console.log('Not signed in.')
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, is it not possible to acquire token without prompting the user to login?

Comment: You mean if the user is already signed in, and you just want to refresh the session to get a new token?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply, no I donot mean a refresh token, I know a refresh is silent. What I meant is similar to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless/ using UserPasswordCredential(user, password), how to achieve this in particular in Javascript, I dont see any such API in ADAL.js

Look at the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607308/how-to-silently-get-access-token-to-user-subscription-azure-batch for type of Authentication possible, what I want to achieve is the second option and in Javascript.

Comment: Username/password flows are not recommended, and not supported by ADAL for JavaScript. There are a large number of scenarios that break if you assume just a username and password are sufficient to sign in all users, and it's generally accepted to be a less secure approach.